# How to get the HTML for a DOM element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Imagine I have the following HTML:

```
<div><span><b>This is in bold</b></span></div>
```

I want to get the HTML for the div, including the div itself. Element.innerHTML only returns:

```
<span>...</span>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Expanding on jldupont's answer, you could create a wrapping element on the fly:

```
var target = document.getElementById('myElement');
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
alert(wrap.innerHTML);
```

I am cloning the element to avoid having to remove and reinsert the element in the actual document. This might be expensive if the element you wish to print has a very large tree below it, though.

Comment: hi - on balance this is probably my best option. a little wary of detaching/attaching elements, I can't screw up the DOM, and I do not expect there to be large trees.

Comment: Unless *myElement* is an element that can't be a child of a div, like  an li, table row or table cell and so on.

Comment: Now that it's 2013, calling "domnode.outerHTML" works on all major browsers (FF since v11)

Answer (score 121):

Use `outerHTML`:

```
var el = document.getElementById( 'foo' );
alert( el.outerHTML );
```

Comment: No it's an IE extension. Although there exist Firefox workarounds: http://snipplr.com/view/5460/outerhtml-in-firefox/

Comment: this is certainly what I need.. although apparently is an IE extension. Am in a WebKit environment - testing now. thanks

Comment: WebKit based browsers seem to support it, but Firefox doesn't.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html it should work in IE, Opera, Safari and Chrome.

Comment: my webkit implementation of outerHTML seems to just return the string content, and not html. innerHTML works as expected.

Comment: Note that outerHTML is part of HTML5, and so should be supported by everyone in time.

Comment: `outerHTML` is supported since FF11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML.

Comment: Firefox supports this from version 11

Comment: For current browser support (96%) of outerHTML see: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_outerhtml

Answer (score 10):

First, put on element that wraps the `div` in question,  put an `id` attribute on the element and then use `getElementById` on it: once you've got the lement, just do 'e.innerHTML` to retrieve the HTML.

`<div><span><b>This is in bold</b></span></div>`

=>
`<div id="wrap"><div><span><b>This is in bold</b></span></div></div>`

and then:

```
var e=document.getElementById("wrap");
var content=e.innerHTML;
```

**Note** that `outerHTML` is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: the problem with getting the innerHTML for the div's parent is that I'll also get the innerHTML for the div's siblings

Comment: My bad, I thought the "put an id attribute on the element" referred to "the element". With your last edit it is a lot clearer that you want to add an additional `div` to the soup :)

Comment: @J-P: if the element is not in the `document`... then where is it, do you care to enlighten us all?

Comment: @J-P: of course you can create elements where you want but this is **no** reason for a down-vote... you won't make much friends around here with that sort of attitude.

Comment: Pretty sure outerHTML has been cross-browser compatible for a long, long time - don't be afraid of using it.

Answer (score 6):

old question but for newcomers that come around :

`document.querySelector('div').outerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

You'll want something like this for it to be cross browser.

```
function OuterHTML(element) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));

    return container.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This would remove `element` from the document when called, right?

Comment: It would, have fixed that now by adding cloneNode, which makes it pretty much identical to  some of the other answers here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a lighter footprint, but a longer script, get the elements innerHTML and only create and clone the **empty** parent-

```
function getHTML(who,lines){
    if(!who || !who.tagName) return '';

    var txt, ax, str, el= document.createElement('div');
    el.appendChild(who.cloneNode(false));
    txt= el.innerHTML;
    ax= txt.indexOf('>')+1;
    str= txt.substring(0, ax)+who.innerHTML+ txt.substring(ax);

    el= null;
    return lines? str.replace(/> *</g,'>\n<'): str;
    //easier to read if elements are separated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as outerHTML is IE only, use this function:

```
function getOuterHtml(node) {
    var parent = node.parentNode;
    var element = document.createElement(parent.tagName);
    element.appendChild(node);
    var html = element.innerHTML;
    parent.appendChild(node);
    return html;
}
```

creates a bogus empty element of the type parent and uses innerHTML on it and then reattaches the element back into the normal dom

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = $('#container').get(0).outerHTML;
```

Comment: Consider adding WHY this is the best solution since OP never mentioned jquery

Answer (score 0):

define function outerHTML based on support for element.outerHTML:

```
var temp_container = document.createElement("div"); // empty div not added to DOM
if (temp_container.outerHTML){
    var outerHTML = function(el){return el.outerHTML||el.nodeValue} // e.g. textnodes do not have outerHTML
  } else { // when .outerHTML is not supported
    var outerHTML = function(el){
      var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
      temp_container.appendChild(clone);
      outerhtml = temp_container.innerHTML;
      temp_container.removeChild(clone);
      return outerhtml;
    };
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.parentNode.innerHTML;
```

Comment: this will also give me any html for the div's siblings though right?

Comment: What's up with the down vote?  The original question had nothing to do with siblings.  This answer was a perfectly valid answer given the original context of the question.

Comment: On the other hand, the original question had nothing to do with a parent.  So, whatever.