# Angular convert page to html that can be downloaded or emailed

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, cordova

Essentially what I am trying to do is load a template that will serve as an html email template. I am building a phonegap app and using an email composer which accepts html. I would like to build the html message by loading a template and simply exporting it into static html. I know that I can programatically do this conversion but for the sake of dry sensible code, I am looking for a much more robust solution.  I have created a directive that grabs a template and injects it into the current view in a hidden div. I then use jquery to grab that div and pass that html to my emailer.

My problem is that what jquery grabs is actually the template code which contains angular template placeholders and not actual values. For example lets say $scope.username = "Jason";

What I need is :

```
<h3>hello Jason, </H3>
```

What I get is:

```
<h3>hello {{username}}, </h3>
```

I've done an extensive search for a method which will simply let me replace all of the template tags with their actual values. Any help would be extremely valuable.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Angular, then avoid jQuery if possible.  Instead just use an Angular function which grabs the HTML you need.  Here's a post showing the javascript to grab part of a dom, so just put that in your angular fn.

[How to get the HTML for a DOM element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript)

If you're really stuck on using jQuery, there are lots of posts about how to create directives for using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't anuglarjs come bundled with it's own version of Jquery(JQLite)? The reason I am using Jquery is for that reason. The matched element is passed into the directive as a jquery object. I did come up with a simple way to achieve what I was looking for. I'll post it as an answer below let me know what you think.