# Javascript: How to get html code from mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get html code element from place where mouse pointer located.
Like if my mouse coursor located on some button I'd like to have code like:
 `<button id="blabla">value</button`> for example.
Is it possible to do?

Comment: Do you mean: [Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript)?

Comment: var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y); this is kind solved my problem, but IT just shows what type of element(input, button, div) but no html element code. How can I get code from elementMouseIsOver

Comment: Like this: [How to get the HTML for a DOM element in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript)