# Shadow DOM innerHTML with slots replaced by assignedNodes()

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, lit

I'm working with a customElement using Shadow DOM like:

```
<hello-there><b>S</b>amantha</hello-there>
```

And the innerHTML (generated by lit/lit-element in my case) is something like:

```
<span>Hello <slot></slot>!</span>
```

I know that if `const ht = document.querySelector('hello-there')` I can call `.innerHTML` and get `<b>S</b>amantha` and on the shadowRoot for ht, I can call `.innerHTML` and get `<span>Hello <slot></slot>!</span>`. But...

The browser essentially renders to the reader the equivalent of if I had expressed (without ShadowDOM) the HTML `<span>Hello <b>S</b>amantha!</span>`.  Is there a way to get this output besides walking all the `.assignedNodes`, and substituting the slot contents for the slots? Something like `.slotRenderedInnerHTML`?

*(update: I have now written code that does walk the assignedNodes and does what I want, but it seems brittle and slow compared to a browser-native solution.)*

```js
class HelloThere extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadow.innerHTML = '<span>Hello <slot></slot>!</span>';
   }
}

customElements.define('hello-there', HelloThere);
```

```html
<hello-there><b>S</b>amantha</hello-there>
<div>Output: <input type="text" size="200" id="output"></input></div>
<script>
const ht = document.querySelector('hello-there');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');

</script>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.innerHTML">InnerHTML hello-there</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.outerHTML">OuterHTML hello-there</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.shadowRoot.innerHTML">InnerHTML hello-there shadow</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.shadowRoot.outerHTML">OuterHTML hello-there shadow (property does not exist)</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = '<span>Hello <b>S</b>amantha!</span>'">Desired output</button>
```

Comment: What are you getting for `ht.shadowRoot.innerHTML`? Why do you need to have the `slot` tags removed?

Comment: Please press that [ <> ] button in the StackOverflow editor and create a executable SO snippet.

Comment: @connexo -- I'm looking at seeing the output with the slot tags rendered as they appear in the browser.

Comment: Again: Why do you need to have the slot tags removed? The result you are getting **is** what your browser renders. That's just how the slotting mechanism works.

Comment: Hi @connexo -- I have an automated testing system that wants to check that a series of complex slots in nested custom elements is actually rendering the result expected from database input.  Seeing the closest to the browser screen output is crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a browser-native way of answering the question (and it seems that browser developers don't fully understand the utility of seeing a close approximation to what the users are approximately seeing in their browsers) I wrote this code.

Typescript here, with pure-Javascript in the snippets:

```js
const MATCH_END = /(<\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*>)$/;

/**
 * Reconstruct the innerHTML of a shadow element
 */
export function reconstruct_shadow_slot_innerHTML(el: HTMLElement): string {
    return reconstruct_shadow_slotted(el).join('').replace(/\s+/, ' ');
}

export function reconstruct_shadow_slotted(el: Element): string[] {
    const child_nodes = el.shadowRoot ? el.shadowRoot.childNodes : el.childNodes;
    return reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_nodes);
}

function reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_nodes: NodeList|Node[]): string[] {
    const new_values = [];
    for (const child_node of Array.from(child_nodes)) {
        if (!(child_node instanceof Element)) {
            if (child_node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                // text nodes are typed as Text or CharacterData in TypeScript
                new_values.push((child_node as Text).data);
            } else if (child_node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
                const new_data = (child_node as Text).data;
                new_values.push('<!--' + new_data + '-->');
            }
            continue;
        } else if (child_node.tagName === 'SLOT') {
            const slot = child_node as HTMLSlotElement;
            new_values.push(...reconstruct_from_nodeList(slot.assignedNodes()));
            continue;
        } else if (child_node.shadowRoot) {
            new_values.push(...reconstruct_shadow_slotted(child_node));
            continue;
        }
        let start_tag: string = '';
        let end_tag: string = '';

        // see @syduki's answer to my Q at
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618519/getting-the-full-html-for-an-element-excluding-innerhtml
        // for why cloning the Node is much faster than doing innerHTML;
        const clone = child_node.cloneNode() as Element;  // shallow clone
        const tag_only = clone.outerHTML;
        const match = MATCH_END.exec(tag_only);
        if (match === null) {  // empty tag, like <input>
            start_tag = tag_only;
        } else {
            end_tag = match[1];
            start_tag = tag_only.replace(end_tag, '');
        }
        new_values.push(start_tag);
        const inner_values: string[] = reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_node.childNodes);
        new_values.push(...inner_values);
        new_values.push(end_tag);
    }
    return new_values;
}
```

Answer in context:

```js
const MATCH_END = /(<\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*>)$/;


/**
 * Reconstruct the innerHTML of a shadow element
 */
function reconstruct_shadow_slot_innerHTML(el) {
    return reconstruct_shadow_slotted(el).join('').replace(/\s+/, ' ');
}

function reconstruct_shadow_slotted(el) {
    const child_nodes = el.shadowRoot ? el.shadowRoot.childNodes : el.childNodes;
    return reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_nodes);
}


function reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_nodes) {
    const new_values = [];
    for (const child_node of Array.from(child_nodes)) {
        if (!(child_node instanceof Element)) {
            if (child_node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                new_values.push(child_node.data);
            } else if (child_node.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
                const new_data = child_node.data;
                new_values.push('<!--' + new_data + '-->');
            }
            continue;
        } else if (child_node.tagName === 'SLOT') {
            const slot = child_node;
            new_values.push(...reconstruct_from_nodeList(slot.assignedNodes()));
            continue;
        } else if (child_node.shadowRoot) {
            new_values.push(...reconstruct_shadow_slotted(child_node));
            continue;
        }
        let start_tag = '';
        let end_tag = '';

        const clone = child_node.cloneNode();
        // shallow clone
        const tag_only = clone.outerHTML;
        const match = MATCH_END.exec(tag_only);
        if (match === null) {  // empty tag, like <input>
            start_tag = tag_only;
        } else {
            end_tag = match[1];
            start_tag = tag_only.replace(end_tag, '');
        }
        new_values.push(start_tag);
        const inner_values = reconstruct_from_nodeList(child_node.childNodes);
        new_values.push(...inner_values);
        new_values.push(end_tag);
    }

    return new_values;
}

class HelloThere extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      shadow.innerHTML = '<span>Hello <slot></slot>!</span>';
   }
}

customElements.define('hello-there', HelloThere);
```

```html
<hello-there><b>S</b>amantha</hello-there>
<div>Output: <input type="text" size="200" id="output"></input></div>
<script>
const ht = document.querySelector('hello-there');
const out = document.querySelector('#output');

</script>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.innerHTML">InnerHTML hello-there</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.outerHTML">OuterHTML hello-there</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.shadowRoot.innerHTML">InnerHTML hello-there shadow</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = ht.shadowRoot.outerHTML">OuterHTML hello-there shadow (property does not exist)</button><br>
<button onclick="out.value = reconstruct_shadow_slot_innerHTML(ht)">Desired output</button>
```