# JS - how to get a string of outerHTML textContent?

Tags: javascript, outerhtml

question in JavaScript - 
I defined an element using tagName, and I want to get the string of it's full define (like "

```
let elem = elementsArr[i].outerHTML.textContent;
```

it returns me undefined.
I'd like some help :)

**Just want to know why my code doesn't work**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the HTML for a DOM element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript)

Comment: i'm flagging this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript

Comment: that's an other solution to solve my problem, but i want to know why what i 've tried to do doesn't work..

Comment: @Aragog what's the html?

Answer (score 1):

> **Just want to know why my code doesn't work**

Because [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) haven't method `.textContent`, so it returns `undefined`.

If you want to get the content of the element you can use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Or if you want only the text, you can use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) on the element.

See example :

```js
d = document.getElementById("d");
console.log(d.outerHTML);
console.log(d.innerHTML);
console.log(d.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="d"><p>Content</p><p>Further Elaborated</p></div>
```

Comment: Exactly - [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)  returns a String (basically). [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)  is a method on Node objects.

Answer (score 1):

`.outerHTML` returns a string, and `String` has no method `textContent` as it is all text content;

You can clear out the HTML with a RegEx or with a `function` - see below:

This returns all the text with none of the tags :)

```js
function strip(html) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  return doc.body.textContent || "";
}

demo = document.getElementById("demo");

console.log(strip(demo.outerHTML));

console.log(demo.outerHTML.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')); // even simpler
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>Some </p>
  <p>text <span>here</span></p>
</div>
```

reference: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

**EDIT**: You can also just use `element.textContent` and it will return exactly what you want

Comment: I think you can use directly `.textContent` instead `.outerHTML` with regex. There is a diffrence ?