# string inside my javascript is been truncated if it contain '

Tags: javascript, string

I have a javascript code which construct an HTML to render inside the browser, here is the javascript part i am asking about:-

```
if (bodyValue && bodyValue.length >= 150) 
    { 
        var displayUrl = "/Lists/Feedback/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ctx.CurrentItem.ID+"&Source=https://***/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/AllItems.aspx"

        newBodyValue = bodyValue.substring(0, 150) + "<a target='_blank' href='" + displayUrl + "'>...[Read More]</a>"; 
    } 
return "<span title='" + bodyValue + "'>" + newBodyValue + "</span>";
```

now if the `bodyValue` contain this charecter `'` then only part of the string will be shown inside the `Span` `title` property.
for example i have this `bodyValue`:-

```
​1. Issue started back in 3 weeks and continued recurring until last week.

2. All the resolutions suggest that the issue is with the OS rather than a scanner issue- she's the only user facing this issue.
```

but the `title` property which will show the tool-tip will only show this part of the string (till it reaches the `'`):-

```
1. Issue started back in 3 weeks and continued recurring until last week.

2. All the resolutions suggest that the issue is with the OS rather than a scanner issue- she
```

so can anyone advice how i can fix this issue? and what other characters can cause this problem?

**EDIT**
now i have updated my code as follow, to create a `<span>` and get its `outerHTML`, as follow:-

```
function bodyFiledTemplate1(ctx) { 

    var bodyValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig; 

    bodyValue = bodyValue.replace(regex, "");
    const span = document.createElement('span');
     span.title = bodyValue;
    span.textContent = bodyValue.slice(0, 150);


    var newBodyValue = bodyValue; 

    if (bodyValue && bodyValue.length >= 150) 
    { 
    var displayUrl = "/Lists/Feedback/DispForm.aspx?ID="+ctx.CurrentItem.ID+"&Source=/Lists/UserFeedbackSystem/AllItems.aspx"
       const a = span.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
     a.href = displayUrl;
     a.target = '_blank';
     a.textContent  = '...[Read More]';
    } 


    return span.outerHTML;
```

but if i have the following string `7:28` inside my `bodyValue` , it will be rendered as `7&#58;28`.. i did not test other characters...

Comment: Can you post some how that function is being used? Are you about to render the result as HTML?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i updated my question,,yes u r correct.. the javascript will construct the html to be shown inside the browser..

Comment: Building a string of HTML is not really a great idea, your `'` is matching your quote in your `title='` and closing.   A better way is access the DOM element and set it's `innerText` property.

Comment: @Keith I think you mean the `title` property.

Comment: @Barmar  yes, but I also thinking about the `newBodyValue` bit too. :)

Comment: @Keith Quotes aren't a problem there, although `<>` could be.

Comment: @Barmar  Yes, but I was also thinking about the `newBodyValue` bit too..  IOW:  It was more an answer on building the accessing the DOM element's directly.   I assume you saw me say `yes` in my last comment.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than dealing with escaping issues, it would probably be a lot more manageable to explicitly assign to the each element's properties directly, rather than to try to concatenate strings together to create HTML markup (which is both inelegant, error-prone, and potentially unsafe). For example, create the `span` using `document.createElement`, and assign to its `title` property:

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.title = bodyValue;
span.textContent = bodyValue.slice(0, 150);
if (bodyValue.length >= 150) {
  const a = span.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  a.href = displayUrl;
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.textContent  = '...[Read More]';
}
return span;
```

Then you can append the returned `<span>` to whatever container you want to append it to with `appendChild` (or something similar):

```
const span = createSpan();
container.appendChild(span);
```

```js
function createSpan() {
  const bodyValue = `Lorem : ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`;
 const displayUrl = 'https://example.com/';

  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.title = bodyValue;
  span.textContent = bodyValue.slice(0, 150);
  if (bodyValue.length >= 150) {
    const a = span.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.href = displayUrl;
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.textContent  = '...[Read More]';
  }
  return span;
}

const span = createSpan();
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this.. i tried your code by the result will be shown as `[object HTMLSpanElement]` inside the browser.. can i try to convert the `span` to string.. as i am working on a third party tool, and i am trying to modify the rendering inside the list.. so maybe i need to return a string rather than a DOM element (as i were doing inside my original code)?

Comment: Did you make sure to use `appendChild` to append the newly created `<span>` like the answer shows? Yes, you *can* concatenate its `innerHTML`, but that's pretty silly to do when you already have the element you want to insert into the DOM.

Comment: as i told you i am building a javascript which should return a string rather than a DOM element. this is how the custom scripts works inside the third party tool if we want to modify the rendering of the list.. now i tried `return span.innerHTML; ` but i will get the text + the link without the parent `span` ..also if the text contain this as part of the string `(09:58 AM)` it will be shown inside the browser as `(09&#58;58 AM)`

Comment: If you have no choice but to transform the result into a string, then get the created `<span>`'s `outerHTML`: `span.outerHTML`. Putting `:` in the input looks to work just fine, see the live snippet edit

Comment: i know about `outerHTML` but on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript  they mentioned that `outerHTML` will only work on IE

Comment: That's not the case, `outerHTML` has worked for a very long time (at least 5 years I think) on both Chrome and FF

Comment: Did you try using `.outerHTML`?

Comment: yes i tried it... but it did not work. I edited my question to show my latest code and the issue i faced.thnx