# How do I show a variable change

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to make a website to track my homework. I want it to show what I have to do. This is my code.

```
<p id="demo">To do now.</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "do"'>Click Here!</button>

var do="5";
```

how do I get "To do now." to 5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the HTML for a DOM element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have Javascript just floating in an HTML file, as your browser won't know what to do with it. All Javascript should either be enclosed by `<script>` tags or in an external file and referenced with a `<link>` tag.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand it, you want the "To do now." to change to 5.

If so then you don't need your `do` variable. You would just change your `onclick` attribute value as follows:

```html
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "5"'>Click Here!</button>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to have the text to change to 5 using a Javascript variable, you would open a `script` tag and insert a function to do so like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeText() {
    var doo = 5;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = doo;
  }
</script>

<p id="demo">To do now.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="changeText()">Click Here!</button>
```

I'm not too sure why you want to do this but I gave you this option anyway incase you did.

As you can see, I changed the `do` variable that you used to `doo` as you can't use the first version as a variable name. This is due to the fact that we use `do` as a keyword for loops. [Check out w3's page on do/while loops here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp).

If you say you're new to programming then I thoroughly recommend using [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) HTML, CSS, and Javascript tutorials as once completed, you should have a much better understanding about how Javascript interfaces with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`do` is a predefined word in JavaScript, so you cannot use it as a variable. try something else. you can try this

```html
<p id="demo">To do now.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="var doit='5'; document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = doit;">Click Here!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend declaring functions in the html structure. It is better to put the `JavaScript` logic in the file separately, as in my example.

```js
var inner = '5';

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inner;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">To do now.</p>
<button type="button">Click Here!</button>
```